# Difference between ごとに、ずつ、それぞれ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances, word-usage, jlpt

What is the difference between ごとに、ずつに and それぞれ?
When are they interchangeable and when are they not?

Comment: Have you seen them used in a similar context, or do they come up when looking a particular term up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

They are almost never interchangeable.

- Aごとに means "for each A".
- Aずつ means "A for each X" or "A at a time". We don't say <sup>❌</sup>ずつに.
- それぞれ is an adverb/noun meaning "each" or "respectively".

Examples:

- 3時間ごとに運動する
  to exercise once every three hours
- 3時間ずつ運動する
  to exercise for 3 hours at a time
- 2日ごとに1回水をやる
  to water once every two days
- 1日に3回ずつ水をやる
  to water three times a day
- クラスごとに2人ずつ代表者を選ぶ
  to select two representatives for each class
- 子供たちはそれぞれ異なる趣味を持っています。
  The children each have different hobbies.
- それぞれのチームに特徴があります。
  Each team has its own characteristics.
- A市、B町、C村の人口はそれぞれ50000人、10000人、3000人だ。
  The populations of A City, B Town, and C Village are 50,000, 10,000, and 3,000, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In simple meaning, I will differentiate them as below

ごとに

- When you do something repeatedly in specified duration/pattern.
- Example1: After every 5 days I visit here. 5日ごとに私はここを訪れます。
- Example2: Every half year he takes a long leave from work. 彼は半年ごとに一度、長期休暇を取る。

ずつに

- It is like "X step at a time".
- Example1: lets improve little by little. 少しずつ改善していきましょう。
- Example2: reply each message one by one. 各メッセージに１つずつ返信してください。

それぞれ

- Some action for each of things.
- Example1: We will talk on each of the topics we have listed. リストしたそれぞれのトピックについてお話しします。
- Example2: Write name of each of the persons.それぞれの人物の名前を書いてください。